# How to convert date stored as VARCHAR2 to 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to convert a date (stored as varchar2) e.g: `4/19/2016 6:42` to this date format `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`.

Source field data type - `varchar2`

target field data type - `date`

source value   - `4/19/2016 6:42`

expected value - `04/19/2016 06:42:00`

Can someone help with the Oracle (SQL) command for this? SQL code would be preferred over PL/SQL, but anything works.

Comment: If the target field is a DATE column then that has no intrinsic format, so you're just converting to a date, not another formatted string. Are your strings in a consistent format? The MM/DD is always that way around, you don't have month names, there is never an AM/PM marker, the hour part is always 24-hour format, etc.?

Comment: OP meant data type (rather than format) - varchar2 and date are data types. I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert in date first and then in char

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(your_var_char_date,'MM/DD/YYYY  HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') 
 FROM  your_table;
```

obviuosly if is necessary only the conversion to date should be used

```
SELECT TO_DATE(your_var_char_date,'MM/DD/YYYY  HH24:MI:SS')
FROM  your_table;
```

Comment: This will convert back to string data type. The OP wanted to convert to date. The solution is in your Answer, but wrapped in an unneeded to_char. It should be just  `to_date(...  ' ... HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge! This was very helpful. I was trying to do it the other way around - to_date(to_char(<date in char>, '<format>'), '<format>')

Comment: You need to keep clearly in mind that to_char takes a DATE or a NUMBER as its input. If you provide it a character string (char or varchar) it will have to attempt an implicit conversion to the proper input data type.  Same for to_date. It takes a varchar as the input. If you supply it a DATE, it will have to do an implicit conversion first, and if you are doing that interactively, it will also have to do an implicit conversion from the resulting DATE back to a string for presentation on the screen.  And implicit conversions (either direction) will eventually bite you in the buttocks.