# ORA-01821: Oracle DateTime Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In `Oracle` database table, I can convert a **DateTime** column with the below query:

```
DateTimeCol = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DateTimeCol , 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:"42":SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

So in the above query, I can change the minute section of the **DateTime** column. But when I try the following, it throws this exception - **ORA-01821: date format not recognized**

```
DateTimeCol = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DateTimeCol, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:' || ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (53, 59)) || ':SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Almost the same thing, trying to update the minute section with a different criteria. I guess, the correct concatenation is skipped here. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: rather than wrting "ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (53, 59)" after ||, you can create a variable =ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (53, 59) and use that variable. also, i dont think you can use functions inside the timestamp format like that

Comment: refer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145681/how-to-convert-date-stored-as-varchar2-to-mm-dd-yyyy-hh24miss

Comment: I believe, the conversion is similar to mine @kumar.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Punctuation and Character Literals in Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) documentation:

> Punctuation and **quoted** text is reproduced in the result.

So you need to enclose the random value in double quotes `"`:

```sql
DateTimeCol = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DateTimeCol, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:"'
            || ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (53, 59))
            || '":SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 1):

`Round` returns a number but you can concatenate only strings. Try this one:

```
DateTimeCol = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(
      DateTimeCol, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:' || TO_CHAR(ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (53, 59))) || ':SS'), 
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

But I would suggest this one:

```
DateTimeCol = TRUNC(DateTimeCol, 'HH') + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(53, 59)/24/60
```

I guess the seconds could be also random, otherwise use

```
DateTimeCol = TRUNC(DateTimeCol, 'HH') + ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(53, 59))/24/60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CAST(DateTimeColAS TIMESTAMP))/24/60/60
```